# App crashes when I run this

Tags: android, view

my app crashes when I press a button with *android:onClick"toastExpert"*

```
public void toastExpert(){

    toastMe(null);
}

public void toastMe(View view) {

    CharSequence text = "Hello Myself Dristi!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration).show();
}
```

Anyone please help...
The logcat details

[image]

Comment: How will we help you, if you don't tell us what's wrong?

Comment: Please post your crash log

Comment: try change `toastExpert()` to `toastExpert(View v)`

Comment: Thanks Phan Van Linh it worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your public method `toastExpert()` is wrong. You have to add following parameters:

```
public void toastExpert(View view){

    toastMe(null);
}
```

Note that every method you use in `android:onClick` has to look like this

```
public void yourOnClickMethod(View view){
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for android:onClick="toastMe" in your button in your xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was trying to check the method call as I am a beginner in Android...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), text, duration).show();
```